# Kubernetes Headless Service resolves to specific interface of a multi-interface Pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a `Deployment` with multiple interfaces using `CNI-Genie`:

```
apiVersion: "apps/v1"
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-shiny-app
  labels:
    app: shiny-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: shiny-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: shiny-app
      annotations:
        cni: "weave, flannel"
    spec:
      containers:
<---snip--->
```

I can see that two interfaces are indeed created in the pod and IP addresses are assigned to it.

```
$ kubectl describe pod my-shiny-app-65c97dfdb9-crl7q
<---snip--->
Annotations:    cni: weave, flannel
                multi-ip-preferences: {"multi_entry":2,"ips":{"ip1":{"ip":"10.36.0.12","interface":"eth0"},"ip2":{"ip":"10.244.1.53","interface":"eth1"}}}
Status:         Running
IP:             10.36.0.12
<---snip--->
```

Now I would like to use the two interfaces for different type of traffic. For example, the `eth0` interface for HTTP traffic and `eth1` will be UDP traffic. My application would bind and listen for the respective kind of traffic on these interfaces.

So far, so good!

Now I would like to use two `Headless Services` for sending traffic to my application. Like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: shiny-app-http-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: shiny-app
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    name: shiny-app-http
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: shiny-app-udp-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: shiny-app
  ports:
  - protocol: UDP
    port: 8805
    name: shiny-app-udp
  clusterIP: None
```

However, both these services resolve to the IP address of the `eth0` interface of the application.
Is there any possible mechanism with which a Headless Service can reliably resolve to a specific interface of multi-interface pods?

Comment: The service using labelSelector to match labels will end up using the pod IP (which is defined in the pod spec `IP: 10.36.0.12`. The secondary IP is mentioned in an annotation only so the service won't recognize it.

Comment: I imagined it would be something like that. My question is, is there no workaround available? Certainly Kubernetes being the de-facto orchestration standard did not ever meet this use case??

Comment: Problem is it's not built to require multiple network meshes within a single cluster and this two veth for a single.pod so no mechanism was built into services to select which card to use

Answer (score 0):

Deployment definition is correct. Could you show me the output of:

```
kubectl exec -it my-shiny-app -- ip addr
```

It will shows if the interfaces were created correctly, each within the subnet of its CNI.

What I am thinking about is creating a service without any selectors:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: shiny-app-http-service
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
```

Because this Service has no selector, the corresponding Endpoint object is not created automatically. You can manually map the Service to the network address and port where it’s running, by adding an Endpoint object manually:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: shiny-app-http-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 10.36.0.12
    ports:
      - port: 9376
```

Accessing a Service without a selector works the same as if it had a selector. In the example above, traffic is routed to the single endpoint defined in the YAML: 10.36.0.12:9376 (TCP).

So you can create two services and two endpoints files with two IP addresses, first IP from Weave (10.36.0.12) and second from Flannel (10.244.1.53).

More about services without selectors you can find [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service).

Comment: Thanks @abielak for the response. I think you did not get my question. I was looking for a solution where a request made to `shiny-app-http-service` will arrive at `eth0` of my app, while a request made to `shiny-app-udp-service` will arrive at `eth1`. Currently, both requests arrive at `eth0` aka the default interface.

As for your question, the output of the `ip addr` command confirms that two interfaces are created correctly with each within the subnet of the CNIs.

Comment: I pasted the Service definition in my post - the Service and Deployment definitions are part of one `shiny-app.yaml`. It is not clear to me how creating the Services using 'kubectl' CLI helps.

Comment: Hey! I edited my answer with new solution, please check it and let me know if problem still exists.

Comment: This is quite an interesting idea, @abielak. I will try it out and let you know.